# Get the difference between two dates from Monday to Sunday

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript that calculates weeks between two dates, so every 7 days equals 1 week:

```
function getWeeksDiff(startDate, endDate) {
  const msInWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

  return Math.round(Math.abs(endDate - startDate) / msInWeek);
}
```

It works well, but now I want to change the logic of this. I want to get 1 week on each Monday to Sunday, and no related to 7 days.
I.E: today is Nov 23, so 24,25,26,27 should count as a week, then from Nov 28(Monday) to Dec 4(Sunday) should be week 2 if I select any of dates between 28 to 4.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `start` and `end` dates are in days?

Comment: The dates format are I.E `11/23/2022` and `11/29/2022`, so I execute the function as: `const weeksDiff = getWeeksDiff(new Date(startDate),  new Date(endDate))` @NijatMursali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the actual weeks between to dates you can use the following:

```
const week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function weekStart(dt) {
    const weekday = dt.getDay();
    return new Date(dt.getTime() - Math.abs(0 - weekday) * day);
}

function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.ceil((weekStart(d2) - weekStart(d1)) / week)+1;
}
```

in that case it does not matter the number of seven days between them.

I have tested it with your test cases, both seems to be working.

```js
const week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function weekStart(dt) {
    const weekday = dt.getDay();
    return new Date(dt.getTime() - Math.abs(0 - weekday) * day);
}

function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.ceil((weekStart(d2) - weekStart(d1)) / week)+1;
}

console.log(weeksBetween(new Date("11/23/2022"), new Date("11/24/2022")));
console.log(weeksBetween(new Date("11/28/2022"), new Date("12/04/2022")));
```

Comment: How can I count this current week as 1 i.e: if I send `11/23/2022` and `11/24/2022` it should count as 1, but now is returning a 0

Comment: I have added additional code snippet. Hope it is solving your issue now.

Comment: Nice!, one more question: why sundays sum +1? it should sum +1 after sunday(on mondays)

Comment: Try to figure that out by debugging the code :) Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct so other people might use it. Thank you.